# How can I sort output, whre each ip-address have a maximum value in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, windows, powershell, sorting, max

)
I have a code:

```
$destination = @(Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Juke\Documents\destination.txt");
$length = @(Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Juke\Documents\length.txt");

function GetTable{
    $i = 0;
    echo ("Make a list IP = Pachet length");

    echo ($destination[1] + "  = " + $length[1]);
    for ($i = 1; $i -le 200; $i++){
        echo ($destination[$i+1] + "  =  " + $length[$i+1]);
    };

};
$res = GetTable;
$res;
```

This is output:

```
95.100.190.60  = 54
95.100.190.60  =  1870
95.100.190.60  =  54
95.100.190.60  =  1869
95.100.190.60  =  54
95.100.190.60  =  1892
95.100.190.60  =  85
95.100.190.60  =  54
95.100.190.60  =  847
95.100.190.60  =  109
95.100.190.60  =  89
87.240.185.160  =  55
87.240.185.159  =  55
87.240.185.158  =  55
87.240.185.157  =  55
87.240.185.153  =  55
87.240.185.150  =  55
87.240.185.150  =  55
87.240.185.145  =  55
87.240.185.144  =  55
87.240.185.143  =  55
87.240.185.142  =  55
87.240.185.139  =  55
87.240.185.139  =  55
87.240.185.138  =  55
87.236.16.99  =  54
87.236.16.99  =  54
87.236.16.99  =  54
87.236.16.99  =  54
87.236.16.99  =  54
```

I have to find maximum value for each Ip-address. As you can see, Ip-addresses repeats in output. I made a table where each ip have the value. Result should be like: IP = Max value.
How can I do it?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `echo` command (which is an alias for [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.1)), just drop a [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.1) on the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.1) which is easy to sort:

```
function GetTable{
    $i = 0
    Write-Host "Make a list IP = Pachet length"

    [pscustomobject]@{ IP = $destination[$i]; Length = $length[$i] }
    for ($i = 1; $i -le 200; $i++){
        [pscustomobject]@{ IP = $destination[$i+1]; Length = $length[$i+1] }
    }
}

GetTable | Sort Length
```

**Notes**

1. [Do not use parenthesis around function arguments.](https://serverfault.com/questions/819763/why-is-it-wrong-to-call-functions-with-parentheses-in-powershell/820149)
2. [Many programming and scripting languages require a semicolon at the
   end of each line. While they can be used that way in PowerShell,
   it's not recommended because they're not needed.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/04-pipelines?view=powershell-7.1#one-liners)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I spent alot of time how to make this output. Here we made a table IP and Length. Bui I have over 5000 strings ip - length. Some IP addresses repeats. If we take all IP addresses without repeat, It would over 100. As result I have to make output IP - MAX Length value. And output have to contain IP without repeats. How can I achive it?

Comment: Please, [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for your initial question, and create a new one for the new issue defined in your comment. For this, create a [mcve], along with a (re)definition of the (new) issue and what you expect as an output. see also [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).